# Upload a file to a storage location

Tags: java, autocad, autodesk

I followed this https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket/ to create a bucket, but couldn't upload the file, I tried [https: // forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/scopes/](http://https:%20//%20forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/scopes/) There are many permissions to get the token, and the last message is that I do n’t have permission. What should I do

Comment: In the first link in your question there is a section entitled _Before You Begin_ where is says that you need to have an _OAuth token_. Do you have this?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have obtained the token, and he keeps reporting "Token does not have the privilege for this request."

Comment: Now after I create the bucket, I reacquire the token and try to find the token with permission, but it still does n’t work. There are several permission ranges that will report the problem of "" reason ":" No write access "}